# Default sort order of the records in SOQL

Tags: soql, default-value, order

I queried

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM User LIMIT 10
```

It generates list of 10 users in some order randomly.  On what basis does Salesforce give these 10 records?  Ordered by CreatedBy ASC? DESC? Name ASC? DESC? But no, it doesn't satisfy any of these conditions!!

But to my surprise every time I execute this, I get the same results.  So, there must be some default ORDER BY.  Can anyone please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

If you read "Order By" documentation it clearly says "**There is no guarantee of the order of results unless you use an ORDER BY clause in a query.** "  It is undefined to get the result in desire order you need to add Order By statement in your query.